# web sockets with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sockets

I am trying to build a dynamic page that updates its contents dynamically without using Javascript.

A friend of mine sugested me Websockets. and when I checked it it was awesome.

Now I can build a Websocket that can be accessed from command prompt. Now my problem is how can I access it with a webpage and also how can I update a page with database values when ever any new value is added.

I checked Google and there was nothing useful.

Please tell me how i can do it. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You *need* to use JavaScript to even create a WebSocket. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: I'm just wondering what you checked that made it so awesome if WebSockets *have* to be used with JavaScript? I must suggest reading about HTTP protocol and how everything works, that's how you'll best understand why JS is required for WS and why you can't do without it.

Answer (score 3):

To use websockets you will indeed need to use JavaScript. WebSockets is part of the HTML5 draft (you can check more here: http://onepixelahead.com/2010/04/30/html5-web-sockets-example/)

Whenever you're trying to access a server from a website, you will either use JavaScript or a third party plugin (like Flash and Silverlight).

I don't really know why you're trying to avoid JavaScript... It would help if you gave reasons for that.

Also, websockets is not well supported at the moment. An important security issue was found in the protocol and only Chrome/ium works with it at the moment (I believe nightly builds of Safari also work).

I would recommend you checking comet servers (such as Socket.IO, although that one is 100% javascript) if you really want something like this, or just go with flash/silverlight.

Comment: Comet is a hack. I'd just stick with regular ajax polling.

Comment: With respect, you seem to have a misunderstanding of comet: Comet servers simply try to provide the most efficient approach to Real-time web. If the best is ajax polling, it will do so. If there's websockets enabled, it will prefer them. Etc. Ajax polling could be called a hack as well. Here you simply have options with fallback from better to worse.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wouln't come arount javascript. But there are a few nice project which may could be usefull for you. e.g. [ape-project](http://www.ape-project.org/) or [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can avoid JavaScript using Google's NativeClient. I don't think there is WebSocket support yet though.